# NSView based custom control drawing update is delayed. Why?

Tags: cocoa, custom-controls, nsoutlineview

I have a view based `NSOutlineView` which displays entries (Source entity) from a Core Data store. The view in the outline view uses a custom control which is implemented as a subclass of `NSView`. This control displays a round coloured marker based on a numerical value (0-7). This value is stored as an attribute of the Source entity and is intended as a method to implement a Finder-like method of labeling.

The whole thing is wired using bindings with IB.

I have attached a screenshot which will hopefully make my intentions clear.

It all works good but for one really annoying detail. When the numerical value is changed (from the right side of the screen) the custom control is only updated when the selection in the outline view is changed. Obviously it would be nicer to have this change reflected immediately but I've failed so far. I've tried various scenario's with `setNeedsDisplay: YES` which were all basically ignored.

Any ideas?

[image]

Edit: I implemented a setter with the custom control:

```
- (void) setLabelValue: (NSNumber*) aValue {
    labelValue = aValue;
    [self setNeedsDisplay: YES];
}
```

Reasoning that the `setNeedsDisplay:` would trigger a re-draw, in the `drawRect:` method I query the value to establish the proper color:

```
- (void)drawRect: (NSRect) dirtyRect {
    // Label value between '1' and '7' indicate that a label was assigned. Determine label color and border color.
    if ([[self labelValue] intValue] > 0) {
        NSColor *aBackgroundColor = [NSColor clearColor];
        switch ([[self labelValue] intValue]) {
            case 1:
                aBackgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:...];
                break;
            case 2:
                aBackgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:...];        
                break;
            case 3:
                aBackgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:...];
                break;
            case 4:
                aBackgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:...];    
                break;
            case 5:
                aBackgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:...];        
                break;
            case 6:
                aBackgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:...];            
                break;
            case 7:
                aBackgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:...];        
                break;
        }
        // Draw border first.
        ...
        // Draw label color.
        ...
    } 
    // Label value of '0' indicates that no label was assigned.
    if ([[self labelValue] intValue] == 0) {
        NSBezierPath *aPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: ...];
        [[NSColor clearColor] set];
        [aPath fill];
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything on the right side of the screen?  Show the code that you use when you change the numerical value.

Comment: If you've built a custom view class to display the colored marker, and you've connected things using bindings, have you implemented a custom binding? How? Did you follow the technique described in [Cocoa Bindings Programming Topics: How Do Bindings Work?](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/HowDoBindingsWork.html)

Comment: @KenThomases: I did not implement custom bindings. See my edit for my -obviously- not working approach.

Comment: OK. Your `-drawRect:` is consulting the `labelValue` property, but that only changes when it's explicitly set *on the view*. It's not consulting the model and you don't provide any reason to believe that the change the user makes using the widget in the detail view is setting the property of the cell view. I assume that's just bound to the model. You either have to implement a binding for your custom view or have the controller pass the changed value to the cell view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reimplemented the whole thing using notifications. I could not get it to work using bindings. Here's what I did:

The controller of the `NSOutlineView` (left part of the screen) distributes views for its elements using the method:

```
- (NSView *) outlineView: (NSOutlineView *) outlineView viewForTableColumn: (NSTableColumn *) tableColumn item: (id) anItem
```

When an entity associated to a file (an image, PDF etc) is added to the outline view, the item view (custom subclass of `NSTableCellView`) for that particular item registers an interest in changes to the `labelValue` property of the entity:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: aView selector: @selector(labelValueChanged:) name: @"LabelValueChanged" object: nil];
```

When a change in the labelValue property occurs (through a click on one of the buttons in the right part of the screen), that controller fires a notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"LabelValueChanged" object:[self selectedSource]];
```

Throught the Notification system, the method `labelValueChanged:` gets called by the item view (in the `NSOutlineView`) which invalidates the display of the custom view components that actually draws the label:

```
- (void) labelValueChanged: (NSNotification*) aNotification {
    // A notification was received that the label was changed. Mark the label object of the receiver
    // if the object in the notification (anObject) matches the object of the receiver (objectValue).
    id anObject = [aNotification object];
    if (anObject == [self objectValue]) {
        [[self label] setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    }
}
```

Thanks to @KenThomases for his suggestions.